# How to get fields with specific array size in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a array int[] field in my table and want to get only these fields who have int[] field size >= 3 and <= 5.

I tried something like this :

```
SELECT cadinality(tt.numbers) >= 3, tt.customer_id 
FROM table_table tt 
LIMIT 50
```

but this return weird column with with checkmark, but it should return fields tt.numbers (only with size => 3 and <= 5).

Comment: please add some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns all rows from your table, but instead of returning the `numbers` column you are returning a boolean expression that shows if the cardinality of the `numbers` column is bigger than 2.

If you want to **limit** the number of rows, you need a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT tt.numbers, tt.customer_id 
FROM table_table tt 
WHERE cadinality(tt.numbers) between 3 and 5
LIMIT 50;
```

```
cadinality(tt.numbers) between 3 and 5
```

is a shorthand notation for

```
cadinality(tt.numbers) >= 3 and cadinality(tt.numbers) <= 5
```